# Plotting shapefile into Google Maps and then plot some of the points

Tags: qgis, r, ggmap

I am currently doing spatial analysis project where I have a shapefile (in Delhi region). That shapefile also consists of ward level data. Sample data set is given below:

```
A    B    C   Ward_No
1    2    3     6
4    5    6    12
43   4    82   26
..    ...  ....
```

I want to plot that file into my Google map (based of `Ward_No`) and then plot some points on it.

So far I have done the following parts in R:

```
# Reading a shapefile with rgdal
library(rgdal)
library(ggplot2)
library(tmap)
s1 <- readOGR(".", "Delhi")
summary(s1)

# Convert it into data frame
y = as.data.frame(s1)

# Plotting that shapefile... Not in top of Google map
z = tm_shape(s1) +
  tm_borders("black") +
  tm_layout(frame = FALSE,
            inner.margins = c(0, 0.25, 0, 0.01)) 


# Create a data frame which having lat/lon data

# No     lon         lat
# 1   77.138015   28.6516444
# 2   77.0738028  28.6387532
# 3   77.1337863  28.7146212
# 4   77.0714699  28.5897667
# 5   77.0919553  28.626676
# 6   77.2860315  28.6320635

# Plot coordinates above the shapefile.

pt <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(coords = geodata[,c("lon","lat")], data = geodata,proj4string = CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84"))
z = tm_shape(s1) +
  tm_borders("black") +
  tm_layout(frame = FALSE,
            inner.margins = c(0, 0.25, 0, 0.01)) +
  tm_shape(pt) +
  tm_dots(size=1, col="yellow", border.col="black")
```

It's working fine but when I try to plot this in my Google map it's not working. The code is:

```
sgmap <- get_map(location="New Delhi", zoom=11,   
                 source="google")

p <- ggmap(sgmap) + z
p
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't mix `ggplot` (`ggmap`) and `tmap` structures. They are two different systems.

You need to either do everything with `ggplot` or `tmap`.

Comment: @Spaceman - You are right..just now solve this problem